# Add a background to a pdf per CLI but don't print it

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf, printing

I am looking for a way (free or commercial) to achieve the following through the command line on a linux machine:

- Add a Background to a PDF
- Don't print the added background

For displaying purposes we need to add a background to our PDF.
I achieved this using `pdftk`.

Unfortunately i am unable to find a way to print that PDF without the background as we have to print on pre-printed paper ( the background of the PDF file)

I found Adobe to offer the possibility to use layers in a PDF and add a property to not print that layer. But it seems to be a GUI only feature.

Is there any way i can achieve this using the command line on a linux machine?

**Additional Info:**

The PDF file has to be signed (QES) so we are not able to create two separate PDF files (one for printing, one for displaying).

This requirement makes a modification (i.e.remove background before printing) impossible as the QES will be verified by an independent party before printing.

Having the Layer set to `never print` would fullfill all our requirements

The initial PDF ( before signing) is created via `cups-pdf`

Comment: I had a similar problem last year (just without the signing part) and could not find a solution. Printing only parts requires Optional Content Groups (OCGs). There are only a few commandline tools which are able to handle these. (pdftk can not). `pdflatex` can create OCGs, but it is really overkill and it does a bad job at handling pre-created PDFs. If you want to try, take a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx

Comment: Thanks!
As i catch the `to-be-printed` text-only document with `cups` this solutions seams feasible if no other solutions is found.
But on the first glance over the ocgx docs i was unable to find a way to have the background always visible in a PDF-Viewer (without user interaction) and always hidden while printing. 
Have to dig deeper.

Comment: ghostscript is also aware of OCGs, but I could not make it create an OCG. There are also tools in the 500+ € price-range which can do this (pdftoolbox for example). But these where out of my budget range.

Comment: Try this one: https://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84318/pdf-layers-ocg-using-latex-dvips ... look for the option `printocg` ... if you find a nice way, please write it up. Would still be useful for me.